# Generate random shape along a point on circumference of circle

Tags: webgl

I am new to webgl ,i created a circle from vertices generated in a loop and i want a random shape(small circle) to be generated on some point along the circumference of the big circle.Can anyone provide me some info on how i can acheive this
Here is my code for the circle:

```js
var vertexShaderText = [
  'uniform vec2 u_resolution;',
  '',
  'attribute vec2 a_position;',
  '',
  'void main()',
  '{',
  '',
  'vec2 clipspace = a_position / u_resolution * 1.0 ;',
  '',
  'gl_Position = vec4(clipspace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);',
  '}'
].join("\n");
var fragmentShaderText = [
  'precision mediump float;',
  '',
  'void main(void)',
  '{',
  '',
  'gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1.0);',
  '',
  '}'

].join("\n");
var uni = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("game-surface");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl",{antialias: true});
  console.log("This is working");

  gl.clearColor(0.412,0.412,0.412,1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


  var vertextShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  gl.shaderSource(vertextShader,vertexShaderText);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,fragmentShaderText);

  gl.compileShader(vertextShader);
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

  if(!gl.getShaderParameter(vertextShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
    console.error("Error with vertexshader",gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertextShader));
    return;
  }
  if(!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader,gl.COMPILE_STATUS)){
    console.error("Error with fragmentShader",gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
    return;
  }



  var program =gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program,vertextShader);
  gl.attachShader(program,fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.LINK_STATUS)){
    console.error("Error linking program",gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
    return;
  }
  gl.validateProgram(program);
  if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program,gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)){
    console.error("Error validating",gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
  }

  var circle = {x: 0, y:0, r: 55};
  var ATTRIBUTES = 2;
  var numFans = 32;
  var degreePerFan = (2* Math.PI) / numFans;
  var vertexData = [circle.x, circle.y];

  for(var i = 0; i <= numFans; i++) {
    var index = ATTRIBUTES * i + 2; // there is already 2 items in array
    var angle = degreePerFan * (i+0.1);
    vertexData[index] = circle.x + Math.cos(angle) * circle.r;
    vertexData[index + 1] = circle.y + Math.sin(angle) * circle.r;
  }
  console.log(vertexData);
  var vertexDataTyped = new Float32Array(vertexData);

  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexDataTyped, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");
  gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);

  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, ATTRIBUTES * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertexData.length/ATTRIBUTES);
};
uni();
```

```html
<canvas id="game-surface"></canvas>
```

Comment: how about [reading some tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org)?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question because WebGL is just a rasterization library so there's literally 1000s of ways to draw something somewhere.

So, you can

- add more points

  You generated the circle points. Generate some more for whatever else you want to draw.
- draw the same circle multiple times in different places and sizes

  Let's say you wanted to draw a small circle on the big circle. [Compute a matrix to scale and reorient](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html) the big circle [where you want it to be](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrix-stack.html), update the matrix, draw the circle again.
- draw more things

  Just like you drew the circle, draw something else like a square and position it at the edge of the circle.
- 1000 more ways...

Comment: can you give me some info if i wanted to draw a hollow circle?